# Creating images by calculating other images

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-classification

I have some categorical images (Y, T, Max, Min, MaxUp, MaxLo). Each image has integer values in different ranges.

I want to create an image MinUp that

```
MinUp = T when Max = MaxUp                                                                                                               
        (T – Max) when Max ∈ [T/2, MaxUp)                                                                                      
        Floor((T - Max)/(Ceiling(T/Max) - 1)) when Max ∈ [MaxLo, T/2)
```

I wrote this code. It runs but gives me wrong results that it completely ignores the conditions in else if and else. All pixels in MinUp equal total_presence.

Cound anyone identify the errors in the code below?

```
if (Max.eq(MaxUp)){var MinUp = total_presence;}  
else if (Max.gte(total_presence.divide(2)) && Max.lt(MaxUp)) {MinUp = total_presence.subtract(Max);}
else {MinUp = (total_presence.subtract(Max).divide(total_presence.divide(Max).ceil().subtract(1))).floor(); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the entire MinUp Image every time and aren't just updating values where the condition is true.

To only update values at locations based on a condition use `.where()`. Something like this could work depending on how you have structured you data:

```
MinUp = MinUp.where(Max.eq(MaxUp), total_presence);  
MinUp = MinUp.where(Max.gte(total_presence.divide(2)).and(Max.lt(MaxUp)), total_presence.subtract(Max))
MinUp = MinUp.where(THIRD_CONDITION, total_presence.subtract(Max).divide(total_presence.divide(Max).ceil().subtract(1))).floor())
```

Comment: It worked out with minor modifications! Thanks for your help :)